# Find element by id not working in Chrome Headless mode

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

- selenium -  3.141.0
- headless chrome=75.0.3770.142

---

Sample code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(CHROME_DRIVER_LOCATION, options=options)
driver.set_page_load_timeout(timeout)

driver.find_element_by_id("keywords").send_keys("some keywords to search")
```

"keywords" is of `<input>` type

The last line is failing in headless chrome and working fine otherwise.

Error:

> driver.find_element_by_id("keywords").send_keys("some keywords to search")
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 479, in send_keys
>       'value': keys_to_typing(value)})
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 633, in _execute
>       return self._parent.execute(command, params)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
>       self.error_handler.check_response(response)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
>       raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
>   selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
>     (Session info: headless chrome=75.0.3770.142)

Comment: is this working in interactive mode?

Comment: try opening the page in chrome browser and inspect the element associated with that id. it may be just a wrapper to the child which you want to interact with. alternatively you can try using `driver.execute_script("use JS code to interact with your element")` and see if that works

Answer (score 5, accepted):

for `headless` browser you have to set the `window size` to fire on event.Because `headless` browser can't `recognise` where to `click` without `window size`.

```
 options= Options()
 options.add_argument('--headless')
 options.add_argument('window-size=1920x1080');
```

Comment: Looking at your other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55239162/3929393a) setting window-size did the trick for me. Maybe you wanna edit your answer.

Comment: If you see Comment section I have asked you is your code working with interactive mode.if yes, that means for headless you need to set window-size to perform an action.

Comment: Oh I missed that. Thanks!