# ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable error sending text in search field using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

I try to use send_keys on a website, which gives me an error of element not interatable.

Here is my code below:

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time

chrome_optionsme = Options()
chrome_optionsme.add_argument("--incognito")
chrome_optionsme.add_argument("--window-size=1920x1080")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_optionsme, 
                          executable_path="/Users/chueckingmok/Desktop/html/chromedriver")

url='https://thelubricantoracle.castrol.com/industrial/en-DE'
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(5)

welcome_sec_one=WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="ctl00_termsPopup_lbConfirm"]'))
    )
welcome_sec_one.click()

time.sleep(5)



driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='search'[@id='txtSearch']").send_keys("Example")
```

![Uploaded the error image][1]

```
Here is the code 

ElementNotInteractableException           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-1415cecd56f9> in <module>
----> 1 driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='search'][@id='txtSearch']").send_keys("Example")

/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py in send_keys(self, *value)
    477         self._execute(Command.SEND_KEYS_TO_ELEMENT,
    478                       {'text': "".join(keys_to_typing(value)),
--> 479                        'value': keys_to_typing(value)})
    480 
    481     # RenderedWebElement Items

/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py in _execute(self, command, params)
    631             params = {}
    632         params['id'] = self._id
--> 633         return self._parent.execute(command, params)
    634 
    635     def find_element(self, by=By.ID, value=None):

/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py in execute(self, driver_command, params)
    319         response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
    320         if response:
--> 321             self.error_handler.check_response(response)
    322             response['value'] = self._unwrap_value(
    323                 response.get('value', None))

/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py in check_response(self, response)
    240                 alert_text = value['alert'].get('text')
    241             raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)
--> 242         raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
    243 
    244     def _value_or_default(self, obj, key, default):

ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=83.0.4103.116)
```

I think the problem is that I cannot locate the element eventually.
So, that's why the element not interactable.
btw, the website link: https://thelubricantoracle.castrol.com/industrial/en-DE#
I want to use the search button.

Anyone can help?

Comment: Can you also copy and paste the stack trace instead of posting a picture of it as well thanks.

Comment: edited it!! @MatthewBarlowe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error message...

```
ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
```

...implies that the [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782684/what-is-the-difference-between-webdriver-and-webelement-in-selenium/52805139#52805139) with whom you are trying to interact isn't interactable (isn't in interactable state) at that point of time.

The two(2) main reasons for this error are:

- Either you are trying to interact with a wrong/mistaken element.
- Or you are invoking `click()` too early even before the element turns **clickable** / **interactable**.

---

To send a *character sequence* with in the search field you you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

Code Block:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("https://thelubricantoracle.castrol.com/industrial/en-DE")
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(lambda driver: driver.execute_script('return document.readyState') == 'complete')
time.sleep(3)
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='button primary' and contains(@id, 'termsPopup_lbConfirm')]"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='search-init']"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='search']"))).send_keys("Example")
```

Browser Snapshot:

[image: castrol]

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable when clicking on an element using Selenium Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55235367/selenium-common-exceptions-elementnotinteractableexception-message-element-not/55236397#55236397)

Comment: Many thanks!!!   May I ask about the xpath of  "//div[@id='search-init']" and "//input[@class='search']" ? As I inspect it, the xpath is  '//*[@id="txtSearch"]' this. Why your xpath is different?

Comment: @JoanMok The website is Javascript based. Initially the search field is `//div[@id='search-init']` but as soon as you click within the field, visually the control is transferred to the `//input[@class='search']` where you need to pass the search text.

Comment: So, I should learn the Javascript to inspect this website?

Comment: @JoanMok Not at all, you shouldn't be worried about the technology involved in building the applications. But while you learn [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) to interact with the [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782684/what-is-the-difference-between-webdriver-and-webelement-in-selenium/52805139#52805139) within the HTML, gradually you will learn the Javascript and other relevant stuffs at the same time. **Note**: I haven't mentioned about JS till you asked for a clarification :) Happy learning

Comment: How can I detect the website is Javascript based or HTML? What about the meaning of this code? 'WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(lambda driver: driver.execute_script('return document.readyState') == 'complete')'   It has the' execute_script' code.

Comment: These days the [DOM Tree](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes) rendered are rarely static. Modern websites uses [JavaScript](https://www.javascript.com/), [Angular](https://angular.io/), [ReactJS](https://reactjs.org/), [Vue.js](https://vuejs.org/), [Ember.js](https://www.emberjs.com/), [jQuery](https://jquery.com/), [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp), etc to render the [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp). But you don't need to worry about the underlying technology stack right away and remain focused on how to deal with them using Selenium.

Comment: Could you show me the whole Javascript of this xpath, please?

Comment: That itself is a bigger question. However it will be unjustified to push you towards Javascript right away, you being a beginner with Selenium. However if you have a specific question feel free to raise it.

Comment: I have also found that some tip tip message that only cover a small part of the html elements may cause this error.