# ElementNotInteractableException python selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-chromedriver

```py
    buttonfinal = driver.find_element(
        By.CSS_SELECTOR,
        "button[class = '_2SQ6OPS1CO _3iCncfMaN4'").click()
```

I tried multiple solutions to click the button but still can't find the solution.

HTML CODE

```
    <button type="submit" class="_2SQ6OPS1CO _3iCncfMaN4"><div class="">Registrati</div></button>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable error sending text in search field using Selenium Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62823489/elementnotinteractableexception-message-element-not-interactable-error-sending)

Answer (score 0):

If you only have a single submit button, do this:

```
button_final = driver.find_element(By.CSS, 'button[type="submit"]')
button_final.click()
```

If you have multiple buttons with the same class, try this:

```
button_final = driver.find_element(By.Xpath, 'button[contains(text(), "Registratin")]')
button_final.click()
```

Tell me if this worked for you or not

Comment: buttonfinal = driver.find_element(
    By.XPATH,
    "//button[@type='submit' and contains(., 'Registrati')]").click()

finally i have find a solution with this.