# ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not element not interactable error sending text to Email field using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I have tried all the posts with the same question from others but none of them worked for my case. I need to write a script to get wholesale prices for the website below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

LoginURL = "https://www.coffeeparts.com.au/customer/account/login/"

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/chromedriver.exe")
driver.delete_all_cookies()

driver.get(LoginURL)

email = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'email')))
email.send_keys("test")

driver.close()
```

For any versions of the code I tried, I always get the same error. I need to run the send_keys method to both email and password fields, then click the login button. After then, I will get the login session information to run web scraper scripts for getting wholesale prices of the items.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ElementNotInteractableException           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-ee71e5f9bc26> in <module>()
     13 
     14 email = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'email')))
---> 15 email.send_keys("test")
     16 
     17 driver.close()

c:\python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.pyc in send_keys(self, *value)
    477         self._execute(Command.SEND_KEYS_TO_ELEMENT,
    478                       {'text': "".join(keys_to_typing(value)),
--> 479                        'value': keys_to_typing(value)})
    480 
    481     # RenderedWebElement Items

c:\python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.pyc in _execute(self, command, params)
    631             params = {}
    632         params['id'] = self._id
--> 633         return self._parent.execute(command, params)
    634 
    635     def find_element(self, by=By.ID, value=None):

c:\python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.pyc in execute(self, driver_command, params)
    319         response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
    320         if response:
--> 321             self.error_handler.check_response(response)
    322             response['value'] = self._unwrap_value(
    323                 response.get('value', None))

c:\python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.pyc in check_response(self, response)
    240                 alert_text = value['alert'].get('text')
    241             raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)
--> 242         raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
    243 
    244     def _value_or_default(self, obj, key, default):

ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
```

Please help. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close. But the locators you were using were identifying the *Email Address* field of the `wholesale-login-form`, instead you need to identify the *Email Address* field of `login-form`

---

### Solution

To send a *character sequence* to the *Email Address* field you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.coffeeparts.com.au/customer/account/login/")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "form#login-form ul.form-list input#email"))).send_keys("vietnguyenswin")
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.coffeeparts.com.au/customer/account/login/")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//h2[text()='Registered Customers']//following::ul[1]//input[@id='email']"))).send_keys("vietnguyenswin")
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: coffeeparts]

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable when clicking on an element using Selenium Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55235367/selenium-common-exceptions-elementnotinteractableexception-message-element-not/55236397#55236397)
- [ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable error sending text in search field using Selenium Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62823489/elementnotinteractableexception-message-element-not-interactable-error-sending/62824100#62824100)

Comment: Wonderful!!! Thank you very much. I also discovered another query that could solve the issue: email = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@placeholder='Email Address *']")))

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone, I still would love to know how you can do that with Selenium. I solved the problem for getting the wholesale price by using different method:

```
s = requests.Session()
```

Then I pass the cookies to the get method:

```
req = s.get(URL, cookies=cookies, headers=headers)
```