# How to click on the element with svg tag containing the attribute focusable="false" using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I'm quite new in Selenium in Python. This time I have a problem with clicking on an element (This is a closing button).

```py
<div class="CloseButton_Background__27knc">
     <svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root CloseButton_Icon__7wksG" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" 
      aria-hidden="true" style="font-size: 36px;">
        <path d="M19 6.41L17.59 5 12 10.59 6.41 5 5 6.41 10.59 12 5 17.59 6.41 19 12 13.41 17.59 
          19 19 17.59 13.41 12 19 6.41z"></path></svg></div>
```

What I do first is: I'm looking for an element on the site:

```
closeButton = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="CloseButton_Background__27knc"]/*[name()="svg"][@class="MuiSvgIcon-root CloseButton_Icon__7wksG"]')
```

The element is found on the page. And then I try to call `click ()` method on it and I get this error:

`selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable`

I'm waiting for the button to be visible.
Please help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can wait until the element is loaded and then perform the click operation.

```
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)
close_btn= wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//div[@class="CloseButton_Background__27knc"]/*[name()="svg"][@class="MuiSvgIcon-root CloseButton_Icon__7wksG"]')
close_btn.click()
```

Moreover, you can also use action chain to click on your element.

```
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(close_btn).click(close_btn).perform()
```

Answer (score 0):

**ElementNotInteractableException** is caused when an element is found, but you can not interact with it.
possible reasons : element is not visible , hidden or behind of another element

```
   closeButton = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
   EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@class="CloseButton_Background__27knc"]/*[name()="svg"][@class="MuiSvgIcon-root CloseButton_Icon__7wksG"]')))
   actionChains.move_to_element(closeButton).click().perform()
```

Note: Dont forget to add below imports to your solution:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as Wait
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```

Javascript :

```
closeButton = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="CloseButton_Background__27knc"]/*[name()="svg"][@class="MuiSvgIcon-root CloseButton_Icon__7wksG"]')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", closeButton)
```

Answer (score 0):

### focusable="false"

As per the documentation in [Managing focus in SVG](https://allyjs.io/tutorials/focusing-in-svg.html):

> The `focusable` attribute defined by SVG Tiny 1.2 is only implemented in Internet Explorer and Microsoft Edge. Unlike `tabindex` this attribute has a boolean value, where `focusable="true"` equals `tabindex="0"` and `focusable="false"` makes the element inert. Besides removing SVG links from the tabbing order by way of `<a xlink:href="…" focusable="false">`, this property also comes in handy to prevent the SVG's root element from unnecessarily receiving focus: `<svg focusable="false">`.

---

### This usecase

To click on the desired element, it would be better to avoid the `<svg>` tag and you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class^='CloseButton_Background']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[starts-with(@class, 'CloseButton_Background')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions on [ElementNotInteractableException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55235367/selenium-common-exceptions-elementnotinteractableexception-message-element-not/55236397#55236397) in:

- [Element not Interactable when using the selenium function find element by name but works when using find element by xpath method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62992942/element-not-interactable-when-using-the-selenium-function-find-element-by-name-b/62994379#62994379)
- [ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable error sending text in search field using Selenium Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62823489/elementnotinteractableexception-message-element-not-interactable-error-sending/62824100#62824100)
- [selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable when clicking on an element using Selenium Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55235367/selenium-common-exceptions-elementnotinteractableexception-message-element-not/55236397#55236397)