# Selenium python can't send keys to second input field

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, display

I'm trying to fill in a webform with selenium and python.
I'm looping trough all input fields and sending each a "Test" string.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/kbu/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://skovbakken.halbooking.dk/proc_error.asp')

all_inputs = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//input[@class='textbox_login']")

for input in all_inputs:
    input.send_keys("Test")
```

Only the first is filled out. Why is that?

This is the error i get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kbu\Dropbox\Python\squash.py", line 10, in <module>
    input.send_keys("Test")
  File "C:\Users\kbu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 477, in send_keys
    self._execute(Command.SEND_KEYS_TO_ELEMENT,
  File "C:\Users\kbu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 633, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Users\kbu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\kbu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=84.0.4147.125)
```

Here is the HTML:

[image: on]

Comment: Hi Kresten! Please check my answer and let me know if that worked for you.

Comment: To complete, you can also directly use `//input[@class='textbox_login'][@type='text']` and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

The [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890) which you have used:

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//input[@class='textbox_login']")
```

identifies exactly 3 elements within the HTML.

The first and last elements are the *username* and *password* field respectively.

[image: login]

But the second matching element contains the `style` attribute value as **`style="DISPLAY: none;`**:

```
<input onkeydown="CheckEnterNoIE('logon', event.keyCode)" name="mf_nnpg0fjm" type="password" id="mf_nnpg0fjm" onfocus="if(this.value==multiform.loginvar6.value){this.value='';}" maxlength="50" tabindex="1" class="textbox_login" style="DISPLAY: none;width:120px;">
```

Hence when your script tries to invoke `send_keys()` on it you face `ElementNotInteractableException`.

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussion on [ElementNotInteractableException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55235367/selenium-common-exceptions-elementnotinteractableexception-message-element-not/55236397#55236397) in:

- [Element not Interactable when using the selenium function find element by name but works when using find element by xpath method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62992942/element-not-interactable-when-using-the-selenium-function-find-element-by-name-b/62994379#62994379)
- [ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable error sending text in search field using Selenium Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62823489/elementnotinteractableexception-message-element-not-interactable-error-sending/62824100#62824100)